# What is the best way to unset many fields in moongoose?

Tags: mongoose

I want to unset fields in my collection. This fields are in an array.

```
var Stuff = new Schema(
 property = String,
_invitedAdmin = [String]
)
```

With mongooDB i can do that :

```
Stuff.update({_invitedAdmin:email}, { $unset : {_invitedAdmin : email} }, callback);
```

How can i do the same with MongooseJS ?

I try :

```
Stuff.find({property:isTtrue}, function(err, stuff) {
{
    for(i=0; i < stuff.length;i++)
    {
     stuff[i]._invitedAdmin = undifined; 
     stuff[i].save();
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work :-(

Comment: Are you trying to remove a single email from `_invitedAdmin` or are you trying to remove the `_invitedAdmin` field itself?

Comment: I want remove a single email from `_invitedAdmin` . In fact i want remove all `_invitedAdmin` of all stuff where property is true.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all instances of `email` from the `_invitedAdmin` field of all docs in the Stuff collection:

```js
Stuff.update(
    {_invitedAdmin: email}, 
    {$pull : {_invitedAdmin : email}}, 
    {multi: true}, 
    callback);
```

If you don't include the `{multi: true}` option it will only affect the first matched document.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely remove the property from your document by setting the values to undefined which will trigger an 
    $unset.

```
doc.path = undefined; doc.save()
```

Comment: I am not very clear in my question.    
In fact _invitedAdmin is an array.  So i try :  

`doc.path[myEmail] = undefined`  

But it doesn't work.